# Sending files to a Rails JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I know there are questions similar to this one, but I've not found a good answer yet. What I need to do is send a description of an object to one of my create methods, which includes some different attributes including one called :image, a paperclip attachment:

```
has_attached_file :image
```

Now I've read that sending the image could be done straight in JSON by encoding and decoding the image as base64, but that feels like a dirty solution to me. There must be better ways.

Another solution is sending a multipart/form-data request, much like the one [LEEjava describes here.](http://leejava.wordpress.com/2009/07/30/upload-file-from-rest-in-ruy-on-rail-with-json-format/) The problem with that one is that the request  params are not interpreted correctly in Rails 3.2.2, and JSON.parse spits out an error when it tries to parse the params, or perhaps it is Rails that is misinterpreting something.

> Started POST "/api/v1/somemodel.json?token=ZoipX7yhcGfrWauoGyog" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-18 15:53:30 +0200 Processing by Api::V1::SomeController#create as JSON   Parameters: {"{\n
>   \"parentmodel\": {\n        \"superparent_id\": 1,\n
>   \"description\": \"Enjoy the flower\",\n        \"\": "=>{"\n
>   {\n                \"someattribute\": 1,\n
>   \"someotherattribute\": 2,\n                \"image\": \"image1\"\n
>   }\n        "=>{"\n    }\n}"=>nil}}, "token"=>"ZoipX7yhcGfrWauoGyog"}

It is quite hard to read that, sorry. JSON.parse(params[:parentmodel]) is not possible here, and I can't JSON.parse(params) either because of the token attribute, JSON.parse(params) throws this error:

> TypeError (can't convert ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String)

Which leads me to believe I'm either approaching this problem totally wrong, or I'm just doing something. Either way, we can be sure that I'm wrong about something. :)

Is there a better way to do this? Can someone point me to any guide/tutorial, or write an answer describing how I should approach this?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**
So I've actually got it working now, but only in tests. I'm not totally sure how this works, but perhaps someone can fill in the gaps for me? This is part of the test code (the image: fixture_file_upload(...) is the important part).

```
parts_of_the_object = { someattribute: 0, someotherattribute: 0, image: fixture_file_upload('/images/plot.jpg', 'image/jpg') }
```

My params[] looks like a normal HTML form was submitted, which is strange (and awesome):

```
Parameters: {"superparentid"=>"1", "plots"=>[{"someattribute"=>"0", "someotherattribute"=>"0", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f812eab00e8 @original_filename="plot.jpg", @content_type="image/jpg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"plots[][image]\"; filename=\"plot.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpg\r\nContent-Length: 51818\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/45/rcdbb3p50bl2rgjzqp3f0grw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20120318-1242-1cn036o>>}], "token"=>"4L5LszuXQMY6rExfifio"}
```

The request is made just like and post request is made with rspec:

```
post "/api/v1/mycontroller.json?token=#{@token}", thefull_object
```

So I've got it all working. I just don't know how exactly it works! I want to be able to create a response like this by myself too, not only from RSpec. :-)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was actually having a terrible time with this question yesterday to do something very similar. In fact, I wrote the question: [Base64 upload from Android/Java to RoR Carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854916/base64-upload-from-android-java-to-ror-carrierwave)

What it came down to was creating that uploaded image object in the controller and then injecting it back into the params.

For this specific example, we are taking a base64 file (which I assume you have, as JSON doesn't support embeded files) and saving it as a temp file in the system then we are creating that UploadedFile object and finally reinjecting it into the params.

What my json/params looks like:

```
picture {:user_id => "1", :folder_id => 1, etc., :picture_path {:file => "base64 awesomeness", :original_filename => "my file name", :filename => "my file name"}}
```

Here is what my controller looks like now:

```
  # POST /pictures
  # POST /pictures.json
  def create

    #check if file is within picture_path
    if params[:picture][:picture_path]["file"]
         picture_path_params = params[:picture][:picture_path]
         #create a new tempfile named fileupload
         tempfile = Tempfile.new("fileupload")
         tempfile.binmode
         #get the file and decode it with base64 then write it to the tempfile
         tempfile.write(Base64.decode64(picture_path_params["file"]))

         #create a new uploaded file
         uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(:tempfile => tempfile, :filename => picture_path_params["filename"], :original_filename => picture_path_params["original_filename"]) 

         #replace picture_path with the new uploaded file
         params[:picture][:picture_path] =  uploaded_file

    end

    @picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @picture.save
        format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'Picture was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @picture, status: :created, location: @picture }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The only thing left to do at this point is to delete the tempfile, which I believe can be done with `tempfile.delete`

I hope this helps with your question! I spent all day looking for a solution yesterday, and everything I have seen is a dead end. This, however, works on my test cases.

Comment: Let me know if it doesn't work in your dev/prod mode, I found the solution to this a few days ago but forgot to write an answer. It is pretty much like yours, only I'm doing it in the model (sending the Base64 data right into an image_data attribute). I like your solution more. Let me know how it goes and I'll help if I can.

Comment: From what I can see the answer is correct so I'm awarding the bounty.

Comment: This is a good answer, but at least in Rails 3/Ruby 1.9 there are some minor holes.  

First, make sure you `tempfile.rewind()` after you write, otherwise you'll get files with 0 length.

Comment: Not enough room in comment field for my input... and I can't edit my above comment any more. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

TomJ gave a good answer, but at least in Rails 3/Ruby 1.9 there are some minor holes.

First, don't attempt to call [] on what might be an UploadedFile object in your params object. Make sure you check that it `.is_a?(Hash)` first, for example.

Also, make sure you `tempfile.rewind()` after you write, otherwise you'll get files with 0 length.

The `:original_filename` key in the parameters to the constructor of UploadedFile is unnecessary/unused. On the other hand, you may want to provide a `:type` key. An easy way to find the value for type is `mime_type = Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extname(original_filename)[1..-1]).to_s`

Here is a version with the changes applied:

```
# POST /pictures
# POST /pictures.json
def create

  #check if file is within picture_path
  if params[:picture][:picture_path].is_a?(Hash)
    picture_path_params = params[:picture][:picture_path]
    #create a new tempfile named fileupload
    tempfile = Tempfile.new("fileupload")
    tempfile.binmode
    #get the file and decode it with base64 then write it to the tempfile
    tempfile.write(Base64.decode64(picture_path_params["file"]))
    tempfile.rewind()
 
    original_filename = picture_path_params["original_filename"]
    mime_type = Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extname(original_filename)[1..-1]).to_s
    #create a new uploaded file
    uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
      :tempfile => tempfile,
      :filename => picture_path_params["filename"],
      :type => mime_type) 
       
    #replace picture_path with the new uploaded file
    params[:picture][:picture_path] =  uploaded_file
  end
    
  @picture = Picture.new(params[:picture])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @picture.save
      format.html { redirect_to @picture, notice: 'Picture was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @picture, status: :created, location: @picture }
    else
     format.html { render action: "new" }
     format.json { render json: @picture.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
```

end

Comment: {:avatar=>
    ["Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError",
     "Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError"]}> Any ideas?

Comment: needs `original_filename = picture_path_params["original_filename"]` before initializing `mime_type`

Answer (score 5):

There is an awesome gem for this purpose if you are using carrierwave

https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64