# Ruby on Rails:Handling image in RoR API using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails application that act as a backend. In my application I have an image uploading field which uses paperclip gem.

It works fine in web view, but I need to upload a image from front-end. I tried in POSTMAN Client by giving image path in JSON format, but it does not works.

Does any one know the format for uploading image? Is there any thing I need to specify in header?

---

#### What I have:

Image uploading from POSTMAN Client

Posting URL

```
http://localhost:3000/users.json   ---   POST
```

Headers used

```
Content-Type  ->  application/json
```

Raw Data

```
{
"image":"C://image/sample.jpg"
}
```

Comment: What doe it mean "upload in json format"? You want to do it with AJAX?

Comment: i have updated my Question with what i have done in POSTMAN Client...Thanks..

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758879/sending-files-to-a-rails-json-api

Answer (score 0):

I have also used rails as backend for iphone application and now i can upload the images from application to s3. Check out the following link and you will get some idea.

http://brainbowapps.com/articles/2010/uploading-files-from-iphone-to-rails.html

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: yes, this was posted way back in 2012. May be I can help you in case you require. Also you can edit this answer and post yours.

Comment: I just need a good working example for sending files to paperclip :-/